# How do I print out the value of the method 'center' in this code - Java

Tags: java

```
public class Point {

    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    Point center(Point other) {
        return new Point((x + other.x) / 2, (y + other.y) / 2); // How to print this value?
    }
    public void printPoint() {
        System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")"); //Value of x and y
   }

}

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Point p = new Point(1,5); 
            p.printPoint();
        }
}
```

How do I print out the value for "center"?

Comment: You know how to print the `Point` called `p`. Calling `p.center()` returns a point. So call `printPint()` on *that* `Point` in exactly the same way you call it on `p`.

Comment: System.out.println(p.center(p).printpoint());

Comment: The `center` function returns a `Point` object. The `Point` class have a `printPoint` function. So just call the `printPoint` function on the object that `center` returns?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(1,5); 
        Point p2 = new Point(3,10);
        Point center = p1.center(p2);
        center.printPoint();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Turamarth